# elementExplorer character escape regressed on Protractor 1.8.0 and 2.0.0?

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, protractor

I am using Node version 0.10.30. 
On Protractor 1.6.1, I was able to escape a single quote character inside the ng-show to return a value. for example:

```
element.all(by.css('[ng-if="user"]')).all(by.css('[ng-show="user.name === \'Jhonny\'"]').getText()
```

However after upgrading to protractor 1.8.0 and 2.0.0, the character escaping doesn't work anymore (I rolled back to Protractor 1.6.1 after the upgrade and it worked again). I then try another code

```
element.all(by.css('[ng-if="user"]')).map(function(ele) {return ele;});
```

The code above crashes elementExplorer with the following error:

```
(node) warning: possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit.
Trace
    at Client.addListener (events.js:160:15)
    at CommandRepl.evaluate_ (C:\Users\test\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\lib\debugger\modes\commandRepl.js:111:15)
    at CommandRepl.stepEval (C:\Users\test\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\lib\debugger\modes\commandRepl.js:33:8)
    at WdRepl.stepEval_ (C:\Users\test\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\lib\debugger\clients\explorer.js:48:16)
    at Interface.<anonymous> (repl.js:239:12)
    at Interface.emit (events.js:95:17)
    at Interface._onLine (readline.js:202:10)
    at Interface._line (readline.js:531:8)
    at Interface._ttyWrite (readline.js:760:14)
    at ReadStream.onkeypress (readline.js:99:10)
```

I have tried running the elementExplorer using Node or directory from Protractor --elementExplorer and both have the same issue. Anyone else experiencing this?

Comment: Likely related to the underlying webdriver APIs that Protractor depends on.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same issue trying to escape apostrophe on by.css locator using elementExplorer from Protractor.
My solution was use double backslash:

```
element.all(by.css('[ng-if="user"]')).all(by.css('[ng-show="user.name === \\'Jhonny\\'"]').getText()
```